# the program skips all the cases in the switch case and goes to the default

Tags: c, switch-statement

i am trying to build a small program that uses the input from the user, and then uses a switch case to perform an action that fits the user input.
i have been tring to find what is wrong in my program, with no luck. there is clearly something i am missing.

here is the code, can you help me find what is wrong with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A 8.5
#define B 7.6
#define C 7.7
#define D 7.7

int main ()
{


    char fuel;
    float amount,total;

    printf("please enter the desired fuel\n");
    scanf_s("%c",&fuel);

   switch(fuel)
   {
   case 'A' :
         printf("how many liters of fuel do you want?\n");
         scanf_s("%f",&amount);
         total=amount*A;
         if(total>150)
         {
             printf("the total price to pay is %.3f: \nYou have won a newspaper", total);
         }
         else
         printf("the total price to pay is %.3f", total);
         break;

      case 'B' :
          printf("how many liters of fuel do you want?\n");
         scanf_s("%f",&amount);
         total=amount*B;
         if(total>150)
             printf("the total price to pay is %f: \nYou have won a newspaper", total);
         else
         printf("the total price to pay is %.3f", total);

          break;
      case 'C' :
         printf("how many liters of fuel do you want?\n");
         scanf_s("%f",&amount);
         total=amount*C;
         if(total>150)
             printf("the total price to pay is %f: \nYou have won a newspaper", total);
         else
         printf("the total price to pay is %.3f", total);
         break;

      case 'D' :
         printf("how many liters of fuel do you want?\n");
         scanf_s("%f",&amount);
         total=amount*D;
         if(total>150)
             printf("the total price to pay is %f: \nYou have won a newspaper", total);
         else
         printf("the total price to pay is %f", total);

      break;

      default: 
      printf("no\n");
      break;
   }



}
```

Even when i input 'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D'  it goes to the default, and not to the apropriate case.
thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Problems such as these are trivial to solve with one.

Comment: Works all right here. Are you sure you typed `A` and not `'A'` or `a`?

Comment: Note that this seems to be specific to the MS specific `scanf_s()` function. Using `scanf()` works (checked with VS 12). However, you should [avoid using the `scanf()` family at all and use something like fgets() instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf) - read the whole line and parse/handle the input in your application.

Comment: @WeatherVane is i am sure.

Comment: @dandan78 i have tried. that is why im writing this here.

Comment: You must read the man page please: *"Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, ...*" So you are missing an argument `scanf_s("%c",&fuel);` should be `scanf_s("%c",&fuel, 1);`

Comment: @GabrielMichaeli What is the actual value of your `fuel` variable then?

Comment: @dandan78 the actual value is the users choise. he choses between differnty kinds of fuel, and then it goues to the switch.

Comment: @GabrielMichaeli we can see that, you were asked to look at the *actual* value of the variable that seems to be misbehaving, because it is obviously not what you *think* it should be.

Comment: You could make life simple by calling `getchar()` and thereby completely skip the quirks of the `scanf` family of functions.,  Note that you should also change: `char fuel;` to `int fuel;`

Comment: the posted code does not prompt the user with the available choices for input, Therefore, the user will see a prompt to enter 'something' but no indication of exactly what the 'something' should be.  Suggest a few printf() statements to display a menu to the user, then if the user does not enter a valid input, loop to display the menu again

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The compiler would have told you that the `scanf_s()` call was not correct.

Answer (score 5):

You havn't used the `scanf_s` function correctly. According to its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) :

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size
>   to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string
>   control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is
>   passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to
>   the buffer or variable.

And checking for errors should also be done, so you should do:

```
char fuel;
if (scanf_s("%c", &fuel, 1) != 1)  {
    puts("Error from scanf_s");
    return 1;
}
```